# Flutter JSON serialization and Setters

Tags: flutter, json-serialization

In flutter I have a simple JSON serializable class for a location with just an ID and a name like this:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'locations_data.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Location {
  final int _id;
  String _name;

  Location({
    required int id,
    required String name,
  })  : _id = id,
        _name = name;

  @JsonKey(name: 'LocationId', required: true)
  int get id => _id;

  @JsonKey(name: 'LocationName', required: true)
  String get name => _name;

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LocationFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocationToJson(this);

  // Why does json_serializable throw a warning?
  set newName(String name) => _name = name;
}
```

when I compile the `locations_data.g.dart` file it says:

```
[...]
[WARNING] json_serializable on lib/src/locations/locations_data.dart:
Setters are ignored: Location.newName
[...]
```

I can not find much about this except [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/285)

Why does json_serializable throw a warning?

Comment: `json_serializable` doesn't know what it's supposed to do with a setter that has no getter.  How is it supposed to represent that in the generated JSON?  It can't, so it ignores it.  Having a setter with no getter (or in this case, a setter with a different name from its getter) is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: The different names were the problem. Got it. Thanks a lot! If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the solution to my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_serializable` doesn't know what it's supposed to do with a setter that has no getter.  How is it supposed to represent that in the generated JSON?  It can't, so it ignores it and generates a warning.

Having [a setter with no getter (or in this case, a setter with a different name from its getter) is a bad idea](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/design#dont-define-a-setter-without-a-corresponding-getter) anyway, and the Dart analyzer would generate a warning during static analysis if you have the [`avoid_setters_without_getters` lint](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/avoid_setters_without_getters) enabled.